# State list for Fiji incomplete

Tags: contacts

Fiji is separated into 5 divisions, however civicrm only includes 4 in the dropdown "State" list.  Here are what the "State" options should be..

- Northern
- Western
- Central (MISSING)
- Eastern
- Rotuma

I am assuming that it would be ok to do
MySQL> insert into civicrm_state_province(name, abbreviation, country_id) values('Central', 'C', 1074);

Is it OK to do this, and if I do this, what will happen if and when Civicrm updates/upgrades ?

Thanks for your help...

Answer (score 1):

In theory you could update this by yourself via SQL.  There are two arguments against this thought:

- The ID won't match anyone else's Civi, which could lead to problems with third-party extensions.
- This is a change that the rest of the community can benefit from.

I would file a ticket at issues.civicrm.org.  If you have the chops to create a Github pull request, great!  If not, no worries.  Please be sure to include a reference to sources showing the missing "State", such as https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_government_in_Fiji.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer my question.  Good advice that i'll follow.. However issues.mayfirst.org doesn't resolve anywhere

Comment: I think he meant issues.civicrm.org.

Comment: For assistance getting this fix into CiviCRM, there's a chat channel at https://chat.civicrm.org/civicrm/channels/dev-newcomers - you should find someone happy to help you through the process. Hi from Dunedin!